# Probability of someone being outside if everyone has 2% probability?

Tags: probability

There are 400 people. Each person goes outside during the day with a probability of 2%. What is the probability of at least 1 person having been outside during the day? How do you reason about this?

I thought about it this way: Let the event $E_n$ be that person $n$ went outside. $P(E_n)=0.02$. So I suppose I want to find $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \ldots \cup E_N)$. However, that would be $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \cdots \cup E_N) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\cdots + P(E_N)$ which is greater than $1$ for $N=400$ and hence is not a valid probability, no?

Comment: The result you're using requires the events to be disjoint. Here it is possible for more than one person to go outside each day, hence the events are not disjoint. In order to do a calculation you need some additional assumptions on the events. A sensible additional assumption is that events for each person going outside are mutually independent. Under this assumption @Gerry Myerson gives the required calculation.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of no one going outside is $(.98)^{400}$. So, the probability of at least one person going outside is $1-(.98)^{400}$.